# Why I'm getting first item from custom ListView?

Tags: android, listview

I have a Custom ListView and trying to pass selected item's text to another activity.

I created public strings in my custom adapters to get this strings from another activity.

My Custom Adapter

```
public class OzelAdaptor extends BaseAdapter {

LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
List<Tactics> list;
Activity activity;
public static String aciklama;
public static String baslik;
public static String özellik;

public OzelAdaptor(Activity activity,List<Tactics> mList){

    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    list= mList;

    this.activity=activity;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return list.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  View satirView;

    satirView=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.satir,null);

    TextView tv1=(TextView) satirView.findViewById(R.id.isim);
    TextView tv2=(TextView) satirView.findViewById(R.id.fiyat);

    Tactics icecek = list.get(position);

    tv1.setText(icecek.getIsim().toString());
    tv2.setText(icecek.getFiyat().toString());

    final String ismi = icecek.getIsim().toString();

    OzelAdaptor.aciklama=icecek.getAciklama().toString();
    OzelAdaptor.baslik=icecek.getIsim().toString();
    OzelAdaptor.özellik=icecek.getFiyat().toString();

    return satirView;
}
}
```

And these are my List texts.

```
     iceceklerim.add(new Tactics("A Lots Of Unit", "Average: 2.9","a text"));
  iceceklerim.add(new Tactics("First Crown", "Average: 4.5","a text"));
  iceceklerim.add(new Tactics("With Mercy", "Average: 4.8","another text"));
  iceceklerim.add(new Tactics("Goblin Barrel Using", "Basic Tactic","different text"));
```

And my another activity

```
public class TacticActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tactic);

    String aciklama=OzelAdaptor.aciklama;
    String baslik=OzelAdaptor.baslik;
    String özellik=OzelAdaptor.özellik;

    TextView tBaslik = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.baslik);
    TextView tÖzellik  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.özellik);
    TextView tAciklama = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.aciklama);

    String deneme= MainActivity.deneme;

    tBaslik.setText(baslik);
    tÖzellik.setText(özellik);
    tAciklama.setText(aciklama);


}
}
```

I want to get text all texts from selected listview per item.

Example; when I clicked to this item `iceceklerim.add(new Tactics("first", "second","third"));`, I want to get 3 texts to per String.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the selectedItem by this way:

In your mainActivity(firstActivity) you can select item in OnItemClickListener by this way:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        case R.id.point_list:
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);

        String item= parent.getItemAtPosition(position)
        intent.putExtra("item", item);
        startActivity(intent);


}
```

and in SecondActivity:

```
public class TacticActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tactic);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String item = intent.getStringExtras("item");
    List<String> mylist = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(item.split(",")));
```

item is what you want.

Comment: Its not my question's answer